# Understanding how to use JS promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I recently began learning about JS promises so that I could interface with Vimeo's video player API and they have me a bit confused. I come from a very synchronous/sequential background (lots of C++) so the asynchronous nature of JS is at times hard for me to comprehend fully.

I am trying to call Vimeo's API function (below) to get the current playback time of a video

```
`player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
     //seconds is what I am looking to get
})`
```

Additionally, I am using Youtube's API (below) for a similar purpose

```
player.getCurrentTime()
```

Now here comes the confusion. Vimeo uses promises and as far as I know youtube does not. So when I do something like the following, I have no problems and everything makes sense to me.

```
someFunction() {
    var time = player.getCurrentTime();
    return time;
}
```

However if I do the same thing with Vimeo's API I have issues with the promise not returning before my return statement and I am left with an undefined return result. The only way I've found to fix this is to move the rest of the code inside of the promise. However, my web app will be compatible with both youtube and vimeo so I am constantly running into an issue of having to duplicate large chunks of code like the following situation.

```
if (playerType == "youtube") {
  time = player.getCurrentTime();
  //large chunck of code relying on the time returned
} else if (playerType == "vimeo") {
  time = 0;
  player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
    time = seconds;

    //copied large chunck of code relying on the time returned
  })
}
```

The youtube approach seems much more efficient as far as amount of code and simplicity of understanding which makes me wonder why Vimeo would use promises in this simple, fast case. Any advice from experienced JS / promise coders?

Comment: promisify the youtube methods that correspond to the asynchronous vimeo methods. win win.

Comment: I disagree @Meier. I was asking if there was a way to avoid copy and pasting large sections of code (provided by the helpful answer below) and then just reflecting on the difference of approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps vimeo `getCurrentTime` function is asynchronous - so using promises, rather than a callback for example, makes it cooler with more street cred - because, "Promises", like bow ties, are cool :p

Anyway, to "DRY" your code, you can simply return the getCurrentTime from youtube in a Promise.resolve()

```
var promise;
if (playerType == "youtube") {
    promise = Promise.resolve(player.getCurrentTime());
} else if (playerType == "vimeo") {
    promise = player.getCurrentTime();
}
promise.then(function(seconds) {
    time = seconds;
    //large chunck of code relying on the time returned
}
```

Comment: `promse` should be `promise` - otherwise the code won't work